# formatting flash drive into a bootable drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, usb-drive

ive downloaded the disk image of ubuntu  14.1 and am now attempting to format my flash drive to be able to transfer the disk image and be able to run it. the problem i have run into is turning the usb into a bootable drive via command prompt. ive created a partition on the drive, however i seem to be unable to select the partition to assign it as a mount point. these are the instructions i followed to clarify any confusion. http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-USB-Bootable

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). If you are using Windows just download Windows version from theirs website, if you are on Ubuntu (or Ubuntu based distribution) install it from terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

I recommend to format your flash drive in FAT32 before using UNetbootin.